# I cannot find memory leak. (SIGSEGV) (segmented sieve of Eratosthenes) (C)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to implement segmented sieve of Eratosthenes in C (im beginner programmer) and it just prints proper output but I'm getting SIGSEGV when I'm submitting in on SPOJ. Can you help me spot the leak?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void segmented_sieve(int *m, int *n, int t) {
int count, i, j, l, sqrt_imax, hlp_imin;
count = i = j = l = sqrt_imax = hlp_imin = 0;
int *imin, *imax;
imin = m;
imax = n;
sqrt_imax = (int)sqrt((double)imax[t]);
int *sieve;
sieve = malloc((imax[t] + 1) * sizeof(*sieve));
memset(sieve, 1, (imax[t] + 1) * sizeof(*sieve));
for (i = 2; i <= sqrt_imax; ++i) {
    for (j = i * i; j <= imax[t]; j += i)
        sieve[j] = 0;
}
int *next;
next = malloc((int)sqrt(1000000000) * sizeof(*next));
for (i = 2; i <= sqrt_imax; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i] > 0) {
                ++count;
                next[count] = i;
        }
}
for (i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
    if (imin[t] <= 2) {
        imin[t] = 2;
        for (j = next[i]; j <= sqrt_imax; j = next[i]) {
            for (l = j * j; l <= n[t]; l += j)
                sieve[l] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        hlp_imin = (int)(m[t] / next[i]);
        hlp_imin *= next[i];
        for (j = next[i]; j <= sqrt_imax; j = next[i]) {
                for (l = hlp_imin; l <= imax[t]; l += j)
                        sieve[l] = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
for (i = imin[t]; i < imax[t]; ++i)
    sieve[i] > 0 ? printf("%d\n", i) : 0;
free(sieve);
free(next);
}

int main()
{
int t, tmp, i;
t = tmp = i = 0;
scanf("%d", &t);
int *m;
m = malloc(t * sizeof(*m));
int *n;
n = malloc(t * sizeof(*n));
for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    m[i] = tmp;
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    n[i] = tmp;
}
for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
    segmented_sieve(m, n, i);
    printf("\n");
}
free(m);
free(n);
return 0;
}
```

I fixed it by changing int to char. now just getting TLE...

Comment: For starters, check whether `malloc` returns NULL

Comment: You do a lot of array access without explicit bounds checking; you could either add in more checking, or run through valgrind

Comment: Also check the result of `scanf` and check that the values that have been read are actually sensible

Comment: Segmentation faults and memory leaks are two different and unrelated things...

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens if you get two values imin = 2,000,000,000 and imax = 2,000,000,010. You should create a tiny sieve for just 11 numbers. But you allocate storage for 2 billion ints which is probably more than your computer can handle.

Comment: Well the input (imin and imax) will be high. But you're right I tried right now for some high number (10^8 and 10^9) and boom SIGSEV gotta fix it. You said about 2 bilions but I used int because i know the input will be 10^9 at highest